# How to iterate elements from sliced array?

Tags: angularjs

JS :

```
var populateRecord = function(data) {
    var chunk = 40;
    $scope.users = [];

    console.log(data.length + "hi");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += chunk) {
        console.log("inside for");
        //  userCount++;
        $scope.users.push(data.slice(i, i + chunk));
        // console.log(temp);


    }
    console.log($scope.users)
};
```

HTML  :

```
<div ng-repeat="record in users track by $index">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isAllSelected" ng-change="userSelectedToggle()" ng-checked="isAllRecordSelected(record)">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="text-overflow">
      <span ng-model="record.dispalyName">{{record.displayName}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <span ng-model="record.mobile">  {{record.mobile}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output on console after 'populateRecord '
2 inside for
2[array(40) ,array(7)]

Now first I want to show 40 elements and after  clicking on button ONLY second array should display on screen. Any solution ?

Comment: Where is the button?

Comment: plz consider a buttton

Comment: So are you able to create an array of arrays where the inner array contains 40 elements?

Comment: yes i am able to splice elemnts

Comment: Can you give me your data array ? I am making a fiddle and I don't want to create this object by myself. Or just put it here direclty and notice me http://jsfiddle.net/brtmzqLk/

Comment: Then whenever the user clicks on a button, increment the index of parent array by one so that the corresponding child array from the array of children will be assigned

Comment: plz create a plnkr or codepen or fiddle. ur snippets are not complete. for eg. where is populateRecord getting called ???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/brtmzqLk/1/  here is plunker .. on loading array of 40 records should be appear and on click of publish message is send to 40 people and then next array of 7 should appear on click of publish message is send to 7 people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to keep a counter and increment the index of users array by one on click of the button publish and store it in a new array which will be used for rendering the UI.

**JS**:

```
    var counter=0;
    $scope.sendBulkMessages=function(){
      counter=counter +1;
      //do your calculations with $scope.parent before assigning it to next 40 elements
      $scope.parent=$scope.users[counter];
      console.log($scope.parent);
    }
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/brtmzqLk/3/